# Adding different unique classes to Wordpress wp_nav_menu?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm trying to put in different `<img>` tags in each `<li>` generated by `wp_nav_menu()`.

Meaning I want `wp_nav_menu` to generate this:

```
<ul id="main-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-219" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-219">
        <a href="">
        <img id="icon-one" />
            Link One
        </a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-220" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-220">
    <a href="">
        <img id="icon-two" />
        Link Two
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Instead of this (the original output):

```
<ul id="main-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-219" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-219">
        <a href="">
            Link One
        </a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-220" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-220">
    <a href="">
        Link Two
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So far I'm trying the `$link_before` parameter but its generating both of them at the same time, meaning its doing `<img id="icon-one" /><img id="icon-two" />` in the middle of the `<a>` tag.

Now I'm looking at walkers, but I'm wondering if there's a clearer way to do it, and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably go with a pure CSS solution and apply the image as a background image. So something like this:

```
#main-menu > li.menu-item:nth-child(1) > a {
    /* 1st background image here */
}
#main-menu > li.menu-item:nth-child(2) > a {
    /* 2nd background image here */
}
```

No need to mess with the PHP code for a simple display issue.

Comment: oops. okay, i get what you mean.

Comment: uh, is there any way to display it before the text?

Comment: @RenoYeo Here is a link to an article showing the technique.  You can look at the very bottom of the article to see it.  http://www.techforluddites.com/2010/02/thesis-replacing-list-bullets-with-images-using-css.html  One other thing to note is that you could possibly use a single image (image sprite) for all of these background images and just vary the background position for each nth-child variation to have it point to the correct part of the image.

Comment: but isn't the text in the <a> tag itself, which is linked to the image, which will push the original box downwards creating an empty space below? Sorry, my brain isn't really working here -- I can't visualize "padding on the text itself" without affecting the <a>'s height...

Comment: Note that in my example you are applying the image and the padding to the `<a>` element not the `<li>` that is how it would differ from the example shown in the link. Sometimes it is also helpful to use `display: block` when styling `<a>` tags in this manner.

Comment: right, I see what I did wrongly there -- I took away the defined height and it works okay now.

Comment: The problem with this method is that you cannot change the menu order. Or you have to change your css at the same time...

Comment: @Strategio If you were passing id's or classes and not using CSS, you would still would need a code change to change how you are naming the icons, so whether the change is in CSS or code, there would still be a change needed (unless of course the OP wanted to go a step farther and associate the icon with the menu entry in the database)

Answer (score 1):

[image: Options panel in menu editing]

[image]

In WordPress menu admin, **you can specify a css class for each menu item**. This way you can use `background-image` css property to customize each menu item. The menu is then rendered like this :

```
<ul id="main-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-219" class="icon-one menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-219">
        <a href="">
            Link One
        </a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-220" class="icon-two menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-220">
    <a href="">
        Link Two
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And you can do something like this for CSS :

```
#main-menu .icon-one {
   background:url('../img/icon-one.jpg') no-repeat 0 0;
   padding: 0 0 0 50px; // depending on your icon
}

#main-menu .icon-two {
   background:url('../img/icon-two.jpg') no-repeat 0 0;
   padding: 0 0 0 50px; // depending on your icon
}
```

NB : If you don't see the css option in the menu item admin block, check it in the option panel on top right.

Comment: I think you can render an image tag with by extending the `menu_walker` class and using it in your `wp_nav_menu`. But it's a heavier modification...